# why implicit conversion doesn't work here?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have this kind of code

```
trait Outer1 {
  type Inner1
}

trait Outer2 {
  type Inner2

  val ev: Outer1#Inner1 =:= Inner2

  def f: Outer1#Inner1
}


object Main {

//  My Problem here  
//  def test1(o2: Outer2): o2.Inner2 =
//    o2.f                                  // <- type mismatch

  def test2(o2: Outer2): o2.Inner2 =
    o2.ev.apply(o2.f)
}
```

Is there any chance to make test1 work? Why Scala compiler can't see `ev` and apply it implicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: First of all, your evidence parameter is not implicit, and therefore also not implicitly found by the compiler:

```
trait Outer1 {
  type Inner1
}

trait Outer2 {
  type Inner2

  implicit val ev: Outer1#Inner1 =:= Inner2

  def f: Outer1#Inner1
}
```

Second problem, a member of a value is [*not* part of the standard implicit lookup scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits). So you need to import that:

```
object Main {
  def test1(o2: Outer2): o2.Inner2 = {
    import o2.ev  // !
    o2.f
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Abstract type checking notwithstanding, if I'm not mistaken, there is no way you can actually *materialise* `Outer2`, because how are you going to give evidence that its member `Inner2` equals `Outer1#Inner1` when `Inner1` is abstract? That is why I am asking for the concrete scenario, because from this abstract layout, I'm not sure you are going to get anywhere.

As far as I can see, the evidence would only make sense for a dependent type, e.g.

```
trait Outer1 {
  type Inner1
  def bar: Inner1
}

trait Outer2 {
  type Inner2
  val outer1: Outer1 { type Inner1 = Inner2 }

  def foo: Inner2 = outer1.bar
}
```

Comment: Well, the first problem is a my fault, I agree. The second one really makes me sad: I don't see any valuable difference between explicit usage of `ev` (like in `test2`) and explicit import of `ev` (like in your answer). I consider this as a design flaw in an implicits' lookup mechanism.

Comment: The solution is to place your implicits where the compiler looks for them, hence the link. Typically this will be companion objects, but the actual solution depends a lot on what your use case will be like, from the example it's a bit difficult to judge. Perhaps you formulate the problem the other way round—state more abstractly what you are trying to achieve, and then ask how to get there.

Comment: I just want my method inside `Outer2` which is bound to return `Inner2` object to use inside itself some code which really returns `Inner1`. I don't want any additional qualification/importing to point compiler that there is an evidence, that `Inner1 =:= Inner2`: the fact that I stated through `ev` value. I want to find out where to place `ev` to be sure that compiler will find it without additional help.